# Where clause in Stored Procedure SQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

New to stored Procedure - Can someone help me in troubleshooting the problem please? I want to achieve something as simple as :

update Table_A set Column_A = New Value where Column_A = OldValue;

but converting this to a Stored Procedure is problematic.

```
alter PROC test_proc
@ColumnValue as Varchar(100),
@TableValue as Varchar(50),
@NewValue as Varchar(50),
@OldValue as Varchar(50)
as
begin

Declare @Pointer VarChar(1000)  

Declare Test_Cur Cursor For     
    Select 'Update ' + TABLE_NAME + ' set ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' = ''' + @NewValue + '''' 
    From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    Where column_name = @OldValue
    and column_name = @ColumnValue
    and TABLE_NAME like @TableValue

Open Test_Cur  
-- Loop the cursor and execution of requests     
Fetch Next From Test_Cur Into @Pointer     
    While (@@Fetch_Status = 0)
    Begin  
      Print   @Pointer 
    Execute (@Pointer)     
    Fetch Next From Test_Cur Into @Pointer     
    End  

-- Closing the cursor and releasing resources     
    Close Test_Cur    
    Deallocate Test_Cur     
    Print 'Update complete!'

end

exec dbo.test_proc @ColumnValue = 'USERCHANGED',@TableValue = 'H_%',    @OldValue = '12', @NewValue = '14'
```

If I remove the line "Where column_name = @OldValue", the problem goes but it doesn't help me achieve my target. Suggestions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mixed internal where with external one, try this ( I couldn't check, may be i misplaced an apex):

```
alter PROC test_proc
@ColumnValue as Varchar(100),
@TableValue as Varchar(50),
@NewValue as Varchar(50),
@OldValue as Varchar(50)
as
begin

Declare @Pointer VarChar(1000)  

Declare Test_Cur Cursor For     
    Select 'Update ' + TABLE_NAME + ' set ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' = ''' + @NewValue + ''' WHERE ' +  + COLUMN_NAME + ' = ''' + @OldValue + ''''
    From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    Where column_name = @ColumnValue
    and TABLE_NAME like @TableValue

Open Test_Cur  
-- Loop the cursor and execution of requests     
Fetch Next From Test_Cur Into @Pointer     
    While (@@Fetch_Status = 0)
    Begin  
      Print   @Pointer 
    Execute (@Pointer)     
    Fetch Next From Test_Cur Into @Pointer     
    End  

-- Closing the cursor and releasing resources     
    Close Test_Cur    
    Deallocate Test_Cur     
    Print 'Update complete!'

end
```

Comment: Is there a reason for which you unaccepted the answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is the logic for your cursor:

```
   Select 'Update ' + TABLE_NAME + ' set ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' = ''' + @NewValue + '''' 
    From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    Where column_name = @OldValue and
----------^
          column_name = @ColumnValue and
----------^
          TABLE_NAME like @TableValue;
```

The first and second conditions conflict with each other.  I think your intention is just:

```
   Select 'Update ' + TABLE_NAME + ' set ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' = ''' + @NewValue + '''' 
    From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    Where column_name = @ColumnValue and
          TABLE_NAME like @TableValue;
```

You might want to rename `@ColumnValue` to something like `@ColumnName`, which seems more apt for its use.

EDIT:

I think your intention is:

```
   Select 'Update ' + TABLE_NAME + ' set ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' = ''' + @NewValue + ''' where ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' = ''' + @NewValue + ''''
    From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    Where column_name = @ColumnValue and
          TABLE_NAME like @TableValue;
```

Comment: ah sorry , pressed enter too fast, i will give it a try.. Thanks a bunch!